# Why Array.asList does not create empty list?

Tags: java, list, unit-testing, testing, iterator

why it does not create empty list?

```
 String fileContent = "";
List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(fileContent.trim().split("[\\s]+"));
```

When I use:

```
System.out.print(wordsList.size());
```

It prints:

```
1
```

What is in a first position in this list?
I have this problem when I want test my iterator.

My test:

```
@Test
    void checkIfWorksWhenNoWord() {
        String emptyString="";

        assertFalse(new WordIterator(emptyString).hasNext());
    }
```

My Class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class WordIterator implements Iterator {

    int index;
    List<String> wordsList;

    public WordIterator(String fileContent) {
        this.wordsList = Arrays.asList(fileContent.trim().split("[\\s]+"));
    }

    public List<String> getWordsList() {
        return wordsList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < wordsList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public String next() {
        if(hasNext()){

            return wordsList.get(index++);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'String fileContent = "";'  -> this cant be split but still stay a string so you get an array with on element that is that empty string.

Comment: An empty `String` is still an `Object` and `split` will not change that.

Comment: So, can I create empty List for my test in some way with this constructor?

Comment: Even stranger: `" ".split("[\\s]+")` gives an empty array. Please don't ask me how this is compatible with what the documentation is telling us :)

Comment: I guess the reason why it's empty is that *"trailing empty strings will be discarded"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Javadoc `split`:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string.

Therefore, `"".split("[\\s]+")` gives `Array("")`, that is, an array that contains a single empty string, because the empty string is the only substring of the input string that is terminated by the end of the input string. Strange, but true.

Comment: Correct, but I think the more relevant line of documentation is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)): *If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.*

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, that's a simple "corollary" that follows immediately from the definition. If the expression does not match any part of the input, then the *"terminated by another substring that matches the given expression"* is always false, and what remains is just the substring that is *"terminated by the end of the string"*, and that's exactly the entire string.